# How to extract the "ZTlhMDNhOGVkZV8xNTY3Mjk3MjAw" value from the respective response in JMeter? This value "ZTlhMDNhOGVkZV8xNTY3Mjk3MjAw" is dynamic

Tags: regex, jmeter, extractor

Response:

```
{
  "service_name": "signup",
  "message": "Sign Up has been done successfully",
  "global_error": "",
  "error": [],
  "data": {
    "session_key": "8f29d7c93e7089841208e94a7d98fc22",
    "user_profile": {
      "user_id": 65,
      "user_unique_id": "e9a03a8ede",
      "dob": "Dec 06, 1998",
      "first_name": "FC7155313",
      "last_name": "FC1791398",
      "user_name": "FCwqim178",
      "email": "fc_slekjbp@mailinator.com",
      "phone_no": "3362239492",
      "balance": "0",
      "status": "2",
      "image": "http://dummy.projects.com/app/assets/img/default_user.png",
      "currency": "$",
      "profile_status": 1,
      "require_otp": false,
      "existing_user": 0,
      "master_country_id": null,
      "master_state_id": "3919"
    },
    "verification_link": "http://dummy.projects.com/activation/ZTlhMDNhOGVkZV8xNTY3Mjk3MjAw",
    "send_email_otp": false,
    "send_phone_otp": false
  },
  "response_code": 200
}
```

I am using JMeter and want to pass "`ZTlhMDNhOGVkZV8xNTY3Mjk3MjAw`" value in next API.
This value "`ZTlhMDNhOGVkZV8xNTY3Mjk3MjAw`" is generating dynamic for each new user registration.
But my regex is not working.

The regular expression that I wrote:

```
,"verification_link":"http://dummy.projects.com/activation/(.+?)","send_email_otp":

Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
```

Comment: Your regex should work. Could you show the code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Your response seems to be a [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) entity therefore there is a high change that it looks like:

```
{
  "service_name": "signup",
  "message": "Sign Up has been done successfully",
  "global_error": "",
  "error": [

  ],
  "data": {
    "session_key": "8f29d7c93e7089841208e94a7d98fc22",
    "user_profile": {
      "user_id": 65,
      "user_unique_id": "e9a03a8ede",
      "dob": "Dec 06, 1998",
      "first_name": "FC7155313",
      "last_name": "FC1791398",
      "user_name": "FCwqim178",
      "email": "fc_slekjbp@mailinator.com",
      "phone_no": "3362239492",
      "balance": "0",
      "status": "2",
      "image": "http://dummy.projects.com/app/assets/img/default_user.png",
      "currency": "$",
      "profile_status": 1,
      "require_otp": false,
      "existing_user": 0,
      "master_country_id": null,
      "master_state_id": "3919"
    },
    "verification_link": "http://dummy.projects.com/activation/ZTlhMDNhOGVkZV8xNTY3Mjk3MjAw",
    "send_email_otp": false,
    "send_phone_otp": false
  },
  "response_code": 200
}
```

so this `"send_email_otp"` bit can easily go to the next line and your regular expression will not match anything in this situation.

I would recommend amending your regex to look something like:

```
"verification_link":\s?"http://dummy.projects.com/activation/(\w+)"
```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: This regex "verification_link":\s?"http://dummy.projects.com/activation/(\w+)" is not working. I am unable to extract verification_link value

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches only the first part of your URL, and not the part that you actually want. Try this instead:

```
http:\/\/dummy\.projects\.com\/activation\/(.+)\",
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G6l5l0/4)

The `(.+?)` part matches between 1 and unlimited time, **as few times as possible** (called lazy match, indicated by `+?`). So you match the first character of whatever comes after `activation/` and then stop. You do not get the entire value, as you want.

Comment: Have you tried your regex with OP string? It matches [much more](https://regex101.com/r/G6l5l0/2) than the wanted text

Comment: @Toto there is a comma at the end, please see my link in answer

Comment: This regex http://dummy\.projects\.com/activation/(.+)\", is not working. I am unable to extract verification_link value

Comment: @C_J are you extracting group1? What result are you getting? See updated regex, maybe that will help you?

Comment: This will break if there is ever an input that happens to have another `",` after the match…